# Doxygen: Missing Call graph for internal functions

Tags: doxygen

I started using Doxygen 1.8.7. I noticed that call graphs are missing when the called function is located deeper in a file. In the below example, the call graph for `function1()` is absent. Is there any dependency on the parsing level?

```
void function1(int cmd, int arg)
 {
  int ret = 0;

  switch (cmd)
   {
    case 1:
      if(arg == 10) { ret = function2(); }
      break;

    case 2:
      if(arg == 10) { ret = function3(); }
      break; 

    case 3:
      if(arg == 10) { ret = function4(); }
      break;

    default:
      ret = function5();
  }

  return;
}
```

Comment: How are the other functions (2-4) defined? Do they appear in the documentation? Are they static? (in that case you need to enable EXTRACT_STATIC). Please provide a more complete example that allows one to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Found the solution.
It worked by increasing the DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES value to 200 instead of default 50.